# Specifying SSL keyfile password in gunicorn command line

Tags: python, ssl, gunicorn

I am using **unicorn** with TLS. The command line looks like this:

```
unicorn --ssl-keyfile=./config/ssl/PrivateKey.key --ssl-certfile=./config/ssl/Certificate.pem  --ssl-keyfile-password=MyPwd
```

I'm moving to **gunicorn** for Production but I don't find a way to provide the private key password. 
**keyfile** and **certfile** are the only SSL command line options available. I don't see any options for **keyfile-password** :

```
gunicorn --keyfile=./config/ssl/PrivateKey.key --certfile=./config/ssl/Certificate.pem
```

For obvious reasons, I don't want to use an unencrypted private key.
How can I provide the private key password?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gunicorn does not support a private key with a password. There's a series of open Github issues relating to this. See [this](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2410) and [this](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1140).

As a work around, you could place nginx in front of gunicorn and let nginx handle the SSL connections.